# Is $\lnot\forall x\;\lnot\forall y\;A$ the same as $\forall x\;\forall y\;A$?

Tags: predicate-logic, quantifiers

Is $\lnot\forall x\;\lnot\forall y\;A$ the same as $\forall x\;\forall y\;A$?
And if so, by what rule? I am trying to find a rule where the above would apply.

I am currently using Hilbert deduction system for a prove and I need to show that:
$$\forall x\;\forall y\;A \implies \forall y\;\forall x\;A$$
But I am currently stuck at:
$$\lnot\forall x\;\lnot\forall y\;A \implies \forall y\;\forall x\;A$$

Comment: No, it is not the same: 'For not all $x$ and not all $y$ holds $A$' $\ne$ 'For all $x$ and all $y$ holds $A$'. I suggest to start the proof over, on a clear page.

Comment: You made a wrong step even before you got stuck. ¬∀x¬∀y A is the same as $\exists x\forall y A$

Comment: Once one realizes that ¬(∀x A) is (∃x ¬A) and ¬(∃x A) is (∀x ¬A), this is entirely automatized, no?

Answer (score 1):

As per previous comments, $¬∀x¬∀y A$ and $∀y∀x A$ are not equivalent; but you do not need it in order to prove that : $∀x∀y A → ∀y∀x A$.

1) $∀x∀y A$ --- assumed

2) $∀yA$ --- from 1) and quantifier axiom : $∀xα → α^x_t$, with $x$ as $t$, by *modus ponens*

3) $A$ --- from 2) and quantifier axiom again, by *modus ponens*

4) $∀xA$ --- from 3) by **Generalization Theorem** : If $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$ and $x$ does not occur free in any formula in $\Gamma$, then $\Gamma \vdash ∀x \varphi$, where $x$ is not free in $\Gamma =  \{ ∀x∀y A \}$

5) $∀y∀xA$ --- from 4) by **Gen Th** : $y$ is not free in $∀x∀yA$

> 6) $∀x∀y A \rightarrow ∀y∀xA$ --- from 1) and 5) by **Deduction Theorem**.

---

In the same way for $∀y∀x A \rightarrow ∀x∀yA$.

---

We can easily "translate" the above proof into *Natural Deduction*, with two applications of $\forall$-elimination followed by two applications of $\forall$-introduction.

Comment: I understand but is there a way around the generalization theorem ie. use something else? I am trying to work it out but I keep hitting a wall

Comment: @user2510809- you can try proving it "by contradiction" ...